# How to migrate from oscommerce to magento 2

Tags: magento2

What are the possible ways to migrate from oscommerce to magento 2?
How we can move product , categories and other data from oscommerce to magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

We have option only to migrate Data from Existing Tool with the help of **Cart 2 Cart Service**

**Link:** [Click Here](https://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/shopping-cart-migration-options/75-oscommerce-to-magento-migration)

As I have Checked:

**What data can be migrated from osCommerce to Magento**

**Products**

- Name, SKU, Full Description, Status, Manufacturer, Tax Class.
- Price, Special Price.
- URL , Meta Title, Meta Keywords, Meta Description.
- Weight.
- Attributes ( Name, Values ).
- Downloadable Products ( Files, Max Downloads ).
- Variants ( Weight, Attributes, Quantity, Price, Special Price ).
- Base Image, Additional Images.
- Quantity, Stock Status.

**Product Categories**

- Name
- Image
- URL

**Manufacturers**

- Name, Image

**Taxes**

- Tax Class ( Name ), Tax Rates ( Country, State, Percent ), Tax Rules ( Tax Class, Tax Rate ).

**Customers**

- ID , First Name, Last Name, Email, Newsletter, Gender, Date of Birth, Passwords , Created Date.
- Billing Address ( First Name, Last Name, Company, Address 1, Address 2, Country, State, City, Zip Code, Telephone, Fax ).
- Shipping Address ( First Name, Last Name, Company, Address 1, Address 2, Country, State, City, Zip Code, Telephone, Fax ).

**Orders**

- ID , Order Date, Order Status, Order Products ( Name, SKU ), Product Price, Quantity, SubTotal Price, Discount Price, Tax Price, Shipping Price, Total Price, Order Comments, Order Status History.
- Customer Name, Email, Billing Address ( First Name, Last Name, Company, Address 1, Address 2, Country, State, City, Zip Code, Telephone ).
- Shipping Address ( First Name, Last Name, Company, Address 1, Address 2, Country, State, City, Zip Code, Telephone ).

**Reviews**

- Created Date, Status, Rate, User Name, Comment, Product.

**Multistore**

- Yes

**Additional Options They Have**

- Clear current data on Target Store before Migration
- Preserve order IDs on Target Store Recommended
- Create 301 redirects on your target store after migration
- Migrate customers' passwords
- Create product variants based on the combinations of options
- Migrate categories and products SEO URLs
- Preserve customer IDs on Target Store
- Strip HTML from category, product names and descriptions
- Migrate images from products descriptions, categories descriptions and blog posts descriptions
- Change products quantity to 100 on Target Store

Hope this will Help you !!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/166480)

Comment: Please check Updated one

Comment: Sorry @Oscprofessionals the vote can not be reverted. I have no rights.

Comment: You can accept this answer if it's helpful for you.